# What to do with delivery boxes when recycle bin is full?

Tags: trash, recycling

We order a lot from Amazon and Amazon prime. The problem is the stuff often comes in individual boxes. Some times, it seems like if you order a pair of socks your going to get two separate boxes.

What neat things can be done to dispose of these boxes? We have recycling, but often the boxes (even broken down), exceeds our recycling bin.

So, how can we dispose of all these Amazon boxes?

Comment: Do you mean as far as alternative uses? Or simply how to get them stored away neatly until there is room in the recycling bin?

Comment: How to stash them away neatly untill we can recycle them.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to clarify!

Comment: Stop buying things

Comment: @Carl, that's not really a viable solution. We get a lot from amazon because it's cheaper and available. I wish they wouldn't pack small things in  large boxes, but I can't fix that. What I can try to do however is recycle. But I don't like having the old boxes around the house all the time as we try to phase them into the bin.

Comment: Build a sweet box fort.

Comment: Get a cat......

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you leave one of the boxes, preferably a larger one than the rest, un-broken down and then use this as a secondary recycling bin - depending on the area you live, the recycling men will be happy to collect the extra cardboard if it's just put next to the bin!
If not, use them as storage boxes until the next collection day!

Comment: Thats what were doing now, it sucks.

Comment: This definitely depends on where you live - for us, in Melbourne, Australia, bins aren't even allowed to have their tops partly open! (ie all rubbish/recycling must fit cleanly inside)

Comment: Yeah, for us the truck will move on by in the lid is not closed completely. I think part of the reason is the "Automated Recycling" program. But honestly the answer is that if the lid is even cracked, your backlog is gonna last another week.

Answer (score 12):

Advertise your free boxes on Craigslist so that others who are needing boxes (e.g. moving, managing space in a small apartment or dorm, selling stuff on eBay) can reuse them.

Answer (score 7):

The solution for my family was to make friends with our neighbors.  They have no problem with me adding recyclables to their bin when there is room.  They are free to add to mine too.  It's rare that we all have space issues during the same week.

Answer (score 4):

As stated by James, you neighbors can be your best friends in this situations. Another idea is a lokal elementary school: they often look for cardboard boxes for making little projects with the kids.

Here in the Netherlands, sportsclub will collect them to sell them to recycling plants for money.

Answer (score 1):

You'll often be able to order an extra recycle bin at a nominal monthly fee through your city's standard waste management company. We do this ourselves during November and December.

Answer (score 0):

leave them out in the rain, they quash much smaller when wet.